# Why do I get a ValueError when explicitly closing stdout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

Python newbie here.  I'm writing a script that can dump some output to either a file or stdout, depending on the arguments passed to it.  When interpreting arguments, I assign either an `open`'ed file or `stdout` to a global variable named `output_file`, which can be used by the rest of the script to write output regardless of what type of stream was selected.  At the very end of the script I `close` `output_file`.  This is proper to do for a file stream, and though it's redundant for stdout, my experience with other programming languages suggests that there's no *harm* in explicitly closing stdout immediately before the program ends.

However, whenever stdout is used for output (and subsequently closed), I get a "ValueError: 'I/O operation on closed file.'".  I know this error is not directly produced by my call to close stdout, but occurs after my script returns.  My question is:  Why does this happen, and is there a way to manually close stdout without triggering it?  (I'm aware that I can easily work around the problem by conditionally closing the stream only when a file was selected, but I want to know if/why this is necessary.)

Very simple demonstrative snippet:

```
from sys import stdout
stdout.close()
```

Comment: Please check your code on any operations with output_file after closing stdout() or put here more code since the given snippet could produce ValueError only if output_file.write(..) been used after snippet.

Comment: The given snippet produces the error all on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that on `python-3.2` there's an attempt at shutdown to flush stdout without checking if it was closed.

The [**issue13444**](http://bugs.python.org/issue13444) is about this.

You shouldn't have this problem in `python-2.7` in releases after the [fixing patch](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/150e096095e5/).

Comment: Glad to hear it's not all down to me not knowing Python.  Thanks for pointing that out. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Once you've closed `stdout` in this manner, you have to be absolutely sure that nothing will attempt to print anything to `stdout`. If something does, you get that exception.

My recommendation would be to close `output_file` conditionally:

```
if output_file != sys.stdout:
    output_file.close()
```

**edit** Here is an example where `sys.stdout` is closed right at the very end of the script, and that nonetheless produces a `ValueError: 'I/O operation on closed file` when run.

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    print "You are now leaving the Python sector."

import sys
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: Nothing in my script prints to stdout after the call to close it.  (The call to close it is the very last line in the script.)  Is there something else I can do to prevent this 'mystery culprit' from using stdout after I've closed it? :-P

Comment: @nonoitall: Sure, you can suppress it (e.g. by assigning `stdout` to some stream that discards everything that's written into it). However, given that at this point you don't even **know** what it is that's writing to `stdout`, blindly discarding that output seems like a rather silly thing to do.

Comment: Does *anybody* know what it is that's writing to stdout?  Even if the atexit portion is removed from your example script, the error still occurs.  (See my snippet.)  The only line in the whole script can be the call to close stdout, and the error will still be thrown.  /me wonders why.

Comment: @nonoitall: What happens when you run a script that consists only of `import sys`? Does that produce any output? (If you're on Unix, run `python xyz.py | wc` to see if you get all zeroes, where `xyz.py` is the script in question).

Comment: Am on Windows so don't have wc handy, but a script with only `import sys` produced no output.  (Redirected its stdout to a file via the command line and the resulting file was completely empty.)

Answer (score 0):

Before closing you can check output_file.closed file:

```
if not output_file.closed:
    output_file.close()
```

And make sure you have no I/O calls to output_file after closing.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.  My call to close stdout is not the direct cause of the error; stdout is open when I close it.  It's after my script returns that something else attempts to use the stream, causing the error.  I'm wondering what the something else is, and if there's a way to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things seem necessary to avoid this error: reset (i) reset stdout; (ii) don't close stdout, close the file to which it was redirected.

```
f=open(filename, 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print("la la-la"), file = sys.stdout)
f.close()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Various solutions to this problem suggest copying the 'original' stdout pointer to a variable before assigning stdout to a file (i.e. original = stdout ... stdout = f) and then copying it back afterwards (stdout = original). But they neglect to mention the final operation in their routine, which is wasted hours pulling your hair out.

Found the solution [here](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/05/19/Redirecting-the-print-function/).